# Concentration of excess reactant

Tags: stoichiometry

If increasing/decreasing the concentration of an excess reactant influenced the percentage yield of a product experimentally, how could this be explained?

I know that in theory, the excess shouldn't affect the yield- since it's the limiting that decides how much is produced. But is there any possible explanation for this result?

Comment: RE: *I know that in theory, the excess shouldn't affect the yield...* Says who?!?

Comment: @MaxW Says almost every other high school textbook that I've read. If the given statement in the question is true, I personally think it would make for a good question to clear the misconception of high schoolers.

Comment: See Le Chatelier's principle https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-chemistry/chapter/factors-that-affect-chemical-equilibrium/

Comment: Yes, but Le Chatelier's principle only applies to systems at equilibrium. If I am reacting some organic goo there is no guarantee that the system reached equilibrium. Kinetics could play a big factor in the yield.

Comment: But even if we use Le Chatelier's principle, wouldnt it still result in the same amount of yield since the amount of limiting reactant is kept the same??

Comment: @MaxW  Could you please help me suggest how I could use Kinetics to explain this??? My teacher said that more concentration of acetic anhydride and the increase in yield of aspirin may be because of the solubility in room temperature (some just returned back to its solid form without reacting)? Do you think this is valid?

Comment: @RaoulKessels gave a good example in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

A very typical situation in organic chemistry is the following:

> $\ce{A -> undisired products}$
>
> $\ce{A + B -> target product}$

Here it is easy to see that increasing the concentration of $\ce{B}$, we will get a higher yield of the target product.

The other reaction can be of many kinds.
$\ce{A}$ can decompose in the reaction medium, can react with itself, with the solvent, with byproducts form the desired reaction, etc.

Comment: Thank you! But does the "increasing conc of B results in higher yield of target product" take into account that there is a limiting and excess reactant?

Comment: Here the idea is that A is limiting and B in excess

Comment: Doesn't:
A⟶undesired products
A+B⟶target product 
just mean that the addition/inclusion of B would produce the target product?

If there is an equal amount of B with A, this would make the same amount as when there is an excess of B. 
How could this prove that increasing concentration of B would result in a higher yield?